# How should I return two lists of objects from one Controller Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having two different list coming from same object. I want to get those two at same time as separate list or join those two same list when returning JSON object.

Here is my code.

```
List<User> userEntity = users.Where(s => s.Id == Id).ToList();

var GetUserNames = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Names.Select(u =>
    new
    {
        Name = u.Name,
        Id = u.Id
    })).ToList();

var GetProfile = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Profile.Select(u =>
    new
    {
        Name = u.Name,
        Id = u.Id
    })).ToList();

return Json(GetUserNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Well which do you want to do - return two separate lists, or join the two together? If you want to return two separate lists, you might want to just use an anonymous type which has them both in...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would prefer to do this differently: the returned items are different types. Rather than returning a bare JSON list with a type discriminator, return a multiproperty JSON object:

```
return Json(new 
{ 
    Names = GetUserNames, 
    Profiles = GetProfile 
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Your returned JSON will have the `{Name, Id}` objects separated into their types, in sketch form:

```
{ 
  Names: [
   {Name:"UserName", Id:"3"}, 
   {Name:"OtherUser", Id: "4"}
  ],
  Profiles: [
   {Name:"Normal", Id:"1"}, 
   {Name:"Admin", Id: "99"}
  ]
}
```

In most JSON.Net client side parsing scenarios (i.e. consuming a WebAPI from a WPF smart client), you automatic mapping (such as from RestSharp) would allow you to deserialize this into a class of the form

```
public class NameId
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class UserNamesResponse
{
     public List<NameId> Names {get; set;}
     public List<NameId> Profiles {get; set;}
}
```

This may be more convenient and clearer to work with than an interleaved list which must be filtered into separate lists for binding anyway.... (or fed through filtering type converters at a performance penalty in the UI binding layer...)

Comment: This is very helpful and it easy to convert in UI. Thanks a lot

Comment: @wpfrookie I totally agree with the above. I thought you needed them within a single list. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GetUserNames.Concat(GetProfile)`.

```
List<User> userEntity = users.Where(s => s.Id == Id).ToList();

var GetUserNames = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Names.Select(u =>
    new
    {
        Name = u.Name,
        Id = u.Id
    })).ToList();

var GetProfile = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Profile.Select(u =>
  new
  {
      Name = u.Name,
      Id = u.Id
  })).ToList();

return Json(GetUserNames.Concat(GetProfile) , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[**Enumerable.Concat Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Update as per comments**

Create a class and enum:

```
public class NameId
{
    public string  Name {get;set;}
    public string  Id {get;set;}
    public ThisType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum ThisType
{
   Username,
   Profile
}
```

Then return that instead:

```
List<User> userEntity = users.Where(s => s.Id == Id).ToList();

var GetUserNames = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Names.Select(u =>
    new NameId
    {
        Name = u.Name,
        Id = u.Id,
        Type = ThisType.Username
    })).ToList();

var GetProfile = userEntity.SelectMany(s => s.Profile.Select(u =>
  new NameId
  {
      Name = u.Name,
      Id = u.Id,
      Type = ThisType.Profile
  })).ToList();

return Json(GetUserNames.Concat(GetProfile) , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: @hutchnoid I understand that we can pass like that but my scenario is I want to fill UserNames in one listbox and Profile in another listbox. I will get only one Json object. How can I differentiate and populate in respective listboxes.

Comment: @WPFRookie maybe you should make 2 functions if they are different. Why return 2 different things in 1 list?

Comment: @peer because I dont want to postback two times with same ID for two different lists.

Comment: @WPFRookie See update, name classes/enums as you prefer.